The text does not completely wrap around the image in beamer
I am making a high school math beamer and meet a problem: the text wraps before it touches the picture? I want the text to wrap before it touches the image (so that more content can be entered and it looks better), or if there is a better option than wrapfigure, it is also welcome.
The code is attached:
\documentclass[11.5pt]{beamer}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}

% set colors
\definecolor{myNewColorA}{RGB}{118,193,188}
\definecolor{myNewColorB}{RGB}{106,172,150}
\definecolor{myNewColorC}{RGB}{94,150,218}
\definecolor{aquamarine}{RGB}{0.5, 1.0, 0.83}
%\setbeamercolor{block}{bg=aquamarine}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=lightgray}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{bg=myNewColorC,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{bg=myNewColorB,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{bg=myNewColorA,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{fg=myNewColorA}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=myNewColorA, fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=myNewColorA}
\setbeamercolor*{caption name}{fg=myNewColorA}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

 \begin{frame}[t]
Known: Tetrahedron $P-ABC$, Point $O$ is the Orthocentre of $\vartriangle ABC$, $PO \bot ABC$, proof：$PA \bot BC$. 
\vspace{-15pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.20\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
\end{wrapfigure}

\bigskip

This is the mathematical proof of this problem, right? Students, think about whether there are other solutions?

\bigskip

\clearpage
Known: Tetrahedron $A-BCD$, $AD \bot BC,AC \bot BD$, proof：$AB \bot CD$.
\vspace{-5pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.20\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-b} 
\end{wrapfigure}

This is not the mathematical proof of this problem, right? Students, think about whether there are other wrong solutions?
\end{frame}

\end{document}


The PDF output is attached:


Unrelated, but you should clean up your preamble. Many of the packages are not necessary in a beamer document.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for your advice and I correct it.

I wouldn't wrap the text around the image. Simply place the text and image side-by-side using columns or minipages.
If a frame is too full for this approach, it will anyway be very painful to look at and you should either reduce the amount of text or split the frame into multiple slides.
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

% set colors
\definecolor{myNewColorA}{RGB}{118,193,188}
\definecolor{myNewColorB}{RGB}{106,172,150}
\definecolor{myNewColorC}{RGB}{94,150,218}
\definecolor{aquamarine}{RGB}{0.5, 1.0, 0.83}
%\setbeamercolor{block}{bg=aquamarine}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=lightgray}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{bg=myNewColorC,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{bg=myNewColorB,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{bg=myNewColorA,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{fg=myNewColorA}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=myNewColorA, fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=myNewColorA}
\setbeamercolor*{caption name}{fg=myNewColorA}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
Known: Tetrahedron $P-ABC$, Point $O$ is the Orthocentre of $\vartriangle ABC$, $PO \bot ABC$, proof: $PA \bot BC$.
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
\begin{column}{.75\textwidth}
This is the mathematical proof of this problem, right? Students, think about whether there are other solutions?
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\bigskip

Known: Tetrahedron $A-BCD$, $AD \bot BC,AC \bot BD$, proof: $AB \bot CD$.
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
\begin{column}{.75\textwidth}
This is not the mathematical proof of this problem, right? Students, think about whether there are other wrong solutions?
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b} 
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}



Thanks for your idea using \column, it does look pretty!
